# How to show only half of bootstrap glyphicon with css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, glyph

I'd like to make a star rating for an item made with glyphicon-star, since it is not possible having glyphs with more than one color, would it be possible to display only half?

[image: half starred]

I'm using bootstrap and I'm working on its source with less.

cheers

```
    <p>
      <span class="view-stats">{$post.numviews|number_format:0} views</span>
      <span class="view-stars pull-right">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star-color"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star-color"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star-color"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star-color"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star star-color" ></span>
      </span>
      &nbsp;
    </p>
```

Thanks, here's the Less snippet

```
 .half {
    position:relative;

    >after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    background:white;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 47%;
    }
}
```

[image: And here's how it renders]

Comment: Do you have the HTML that we can look at? There are many ways to approach your problem but if there is no code, it's difficult to help.

Comment: Show your code please .

Comment: added part of the code, for now of course, the number of glyphicon-stars is static, but the db will give something like 3.5, 4, 4.5 [...]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

demo - http://www.bootply.com/10XzUrAamb

changed `left` to `47%` so that it adjusts with different font sizes

you can do something like this

```
.half {
    position:relative;
}
half:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    background:white;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 47%;
}
```

Comment: Probably a better idea to use relative dimensions, like `width: 50%` so that we can accommodate font-size changes.